# Does anyone know any details on the recent security release notifications?

Tags: security

All our EE2 sites are displaying:

"An ExpressionEngine version 2.11.6, build 20170207 has been released as a security release"

Does anyone have any details about what security vulnerabilities are being addressed? Are they specific to version 2.11 or a general security vulnerability in all EE2 sites?

Answer (score 2):

You'll discover all patch notes [here](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/about/changelog.html#version-2-11-6) in the changelog.

Security patches are a combination of both EE & underlying frameworks. EE is pretty resilient and a lot of security issues are more server side orientated.

Comment: Thanks Stuart.

I’m also trying to find out how far back the system vulnerability goes. We’ve built 200+ EE2 sites, and we’re trying to see how many of them are affected.

Like, do all of them have the security bug or just the ones running EE2.8+?

Answer (score 1):

I found out from Robin Sowell with Ellis Lab that the latest security release fixes a previously unknown issue in CodeIgnitor, which is at the core of version 2.

So this definitely affects all installs of EE2.